# Zomato API calls with R httr package not returning records when adding string query

Tags: r, rest, httr, zomato-api

I am using the Zomato API with R's httr package to get restaurant data in JSON.  When I call the Zomato API using the following code block, I get some records back and the GET() call seems to work fine.

```
require(httr)

URL <- 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?'

request <- GET(URL,
           add_headers(User_key="#######_MY_API_KEY##############"),
           query=list(entity_id = '94753', 
                      entity_type = 'zone'))
content(request)
```

In the next code block, I make one modification to the code in order to do a text search. This API call returns 0 records, but it should return 2 - I know this because Zomato has an API testing tool at https://developers.zomato.com/documentation, which allows you to (among other things) enter your API key and some attribute values to generate API calls, and see the records returned.
I cannot understand why the following GET() returns 0 records.  Suggestions?

```
request <- GET(URL,
           add_headers(User_key="#######_MY_API_KEY##############"),
           query=list(entity_id = '94753', 
                      entity_type = 'zone',
                      q = 'border')) #added parameter and value
content(request)
```

Comment: `URL` in first and `URLs` in second, but I doubt this is your problem.

Comment: I wish :)  Edited.

Comment: use `httr::verbose()` to see verbose curl output for what's sent and received, may help locate problem

Comment: and try and drop the trailing ? in the URL

Answer (score 0):

After reloading the R environment and running the script from scratch, it appears to work fine - the Get() call in the second block retrieves the 2 records that it should.  I suspect that there was something I had set in the environment that was messing it up - perhaps epi99 was right, but just about another typo.